# Is every basin of attraction completely invariant?

Tags: dynamical-systems, fractals, complex-dynamics, basins-of-attraction

I can't seem to find a definitive answer in the literature.  I believe the answer is yes, but my focus has been on the rational maps on the Riemann sphere.  At the very least I'm confident that if the rational map is conjugate to a polynomial, then the answer ought to be yes.  If it isn't true, can someone provide a counter example, and also explain what is flawed with my reasoning?

The relevant definitions and my reasoning follow.

Given a holomorphic map $R$, define the **basin of attraction** of $R$ containing the fixed point $c$ by

$B_{R,c}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}R^{\circ n}(z) = c\}$,

where $R^{\circ n}$ denotes $R$ composed with itself $n$ times.

A set $U$ is **completely invariant** with respect to $R$ if 
  $$R(U)\subset U$$ 
and

$$R^{-1}(U)\subset U$$

***If $R$ is a polynomial with a basin of attraction $B_{R,c}$, then $B_{R,c}$ is completely invariant***

Proof: That $R(B_{R,c})\subset B_{R,c}$ is clear.  This can be easily found in the literature.  To see that $R^{-1}(B_{R,c})\subset B_{R,c}$, suppose $z\in R^{-1}(B_{R,c})$, then there is some $w\in B_{R,c}$ such that $R(z) = w$, but then $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}R^{\circ n}(z) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}R^{\circ n-1}(R(z)) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}R^{\circ n-1}(w) = c$$

Thus $z\in B_{R,c}$ and so $R^{-1}(B_{R,c})\subset B_{R,c}$, concluding the proof.

The result is extended quite easily to rational maps conjugate to a  polynomial via Conjugacy theory.  I would expect this to be true in greater generality, but again, because I have not seen such a result in the literature, it seems that it might not be true.  Any thoughts and suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I guess it depends.  Does such a condition imply that the basin of attraction of the attractor is completely invariant under the evolution operator?

Comment: if $X$ is any topological space, $c$ is any point of $X$ and $R$ is any  function $X \to X$, then you should be able to copy paste your proof to show that $B_{R,c}$ is completely invariant.

Comment: @mercio is right. Maybe it would be easier for you JTipton to deal with metric spaces $(X,d).$ In your case $(X,d)=(\mathbb{C},||\cdot||)$ or $(S^2,d)$ in Riemann sphere case.

Comment: The basin of attraction is completely invariant by definition (since images and preimages of a point converging to the attractor also converge to the attractor ...) If it is indeed not stated in the literature, then it would probably be because it is considered obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, every basin of attraction is completely invariant even for any function.

This result can be generalised to metric spaces ( even to topological, but we stick with metric).

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $R:X\to X$ be a function and $c\in X$ a point. Denote $$B_{R,c}=\{x\in X\:\lim_{x\to\infty}R^n(x)=c\}.$$
We will show that $R(B_{R,c})\subset B_{R,c}$ and $R^{-1}(B_{R,c})\subset B_{R,c}$.

$R(B_{R,c})\subset B_{R,c}:$ Let $R(z)\in R(B_{R,c}).$ Then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}R^n(R(z))=\lim_{n\to\infty}R^{n+1}(z)=c.$$
Hence $R(z)\in B_{R,c}.$

$R^{-1}(B_{R,c})\subset B_{R,c}:$ Suppose $z\in R^{−1}(B_{R,c})$, then there is some $w\in B_{R,c}$ such that $R(z)=w$, but then

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}R^{ n}(z) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}R^{n-1}(R(z)) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}R^{ n-1}(w) = c.$$

In your case we have $(X,d)=(\mathbb{C},||\cdot||)$ or $(S^2,d)$ in Riemann sphere case.

---

If you want to find this type of results in literature, you should look in books about **discrete dynamical systems.**

Comment: Thanks.  I've been reading Beardon's Iteration of Rational Functions, Milnor's Dynamics in One Complex Variable, and Carleson/Gamelin's Complex Dynamics, and I haven't seen any mention of this result.

Comment: @JTipton I looked into few books and I do not find such sets $B_{R,c}.$ Maybe they are not very interesting from dynamical point of view. Additionally notice that we do not assume $R$ to be continuous and the proof is very easy. So I guess that this result does not appear in literature due to its obviousity and lack of applicaitons.

Comment: You should be able to find them in the books I mentioned.  Sometimes they talk about the immediate basin of attraction, which is a subset of the $B_{R,c}$.  The boundary of a given basin of attraction is the Julia set of the corresponding rational map.  I agree that it seems obvious, and I too haven't seen much application in the literature.  You can however do some nice things with it if you are familiar with reproducing kernels.